# Trumbowyg not formatting text (Bold, Italic, Strikethrough)

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, trumbowyg

I'm using the Trumbowyg WYSIWYG text editor http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/

The only buttons i'm using are the Bold, Italic, Strikethrough and InsertImage. Right now, the only button that works is the InsertImage. When I select text and apply Bold, Italic or Strikethrough, it does nothing. When the post is submitted, it also doesn't render Bold, Italic or Strikethrough. Only plain text. Keep in mind the rendered post has a `safe` template filter:

```
{{instance.content|safe}}
```

When I remove the `safe`, it doesn't render the formatting but it renders the actual html like this:

```
<strong>Text</strong>
```

Regardless of all this, when making a post the text editor doesn't format it properly:

```
**bold text**
```

it just does this:

```
bold text
```

The only thing that renders properly is the InsertImage. When I insert the image it shows up immediately, and also renders fine after posting.

Any idea why the other formatting doesn't work?

Comment: do you have css code which resets all css styles? That might be the issue.

Comment: Yep I had a css reset which affected it, it's all good now. thanks.